# Windows Store App play any files

Tags: windows, xaml

I have list of files

1. D:\Videos\Video_1.mp4
2. \\SOME-NETWORK-PC\Shared\Video_2.mp4

   ...

I need play files in MediaElement.

```cs
MediaElement.Source = new Uri(url from list);
MediaElement.Play();
```

but I have this error:

> **MF_MEDIA_ENGINE_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED**

Default installed in windows 10 "Movies & TV" - can play video from this list.

Comment: See [File access and permissions (Windows Runtime apps)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In Windows Store App user must allow access to file/folder with FileOpenPicker/FolderPicker
2. After getting StorageFile (PickSingleFileAsync), save to own list and save to FutureAccessList

```cs
StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace(ID, StorageFile)
```

3. In next time use FutureAccessList

```cs
StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFileAsync(ID)
```